# Linking against tcl when building matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to build matplotlib from source. I have pre-built tcl and tk from source at a local location: `/home/my_user_name/local`, and added `/home/my_user_name/local` to `basedir` in `setupext.py`.

However, when I run

```
python setup.py build
```

it eventually it stops with:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I went to `/home/my_user_name/local/lib` and saw the following

```
find . -name '*tcl*'
```

and found:

```
./libtclstub8.5.a
./tcl8.5
./libtcl8.5.so
./tcl8
./tclConfig.sh
```

Which file is matplotlib trying to link to? I don't seem to have `tcl.so`

Answer (score 0):

The file needed is libtcl.so, which is probably a symbolic link to libtcl8.5.so. Perhaps you need to install the development version of Tcl, which is different from system to system. I am sorry, I cannot do more to help.